# Get index of an rdd in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an **RDD** **`RDD[Employee]`** where columns in Employee are id, first_name, last_name, dob
I want to set the value of id with the index value of `RDD[Employee]`. How do I do that?
I am able to get the index using `rdd.zipWithIndex()`, but I dont know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map each element to the new desired element:

```
rdd.zipWithIndex()
   .map{case(elem, index) => elem.copy(id = index.toInt)}
```

If your Employee class is not a case class, or if it lacks `copy` method you can do this:

```
rdd.zipWithIndex()
   .map{case(elem, index) => Employee(index.toInt, elem.first_name, elem.last_name)}
```

- First, with `zipWithIndex` you obtain the index for each row, this
  turns your RDD in a Tupled RDD where the first element is your
  employee (which i called elem in my example) and the second is the
  index
- Then you can just create a new Employee with the index as id
  and the same first and last_name as the original

Note: By default the index created by the zip method is a Long, since in my Employee class the id is a int, i need to turn it an int. You may not need this if your id is already a Long.